# Combolist div in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div with some searchbox on top and on click of top it display list and then i can select list and display into box.

Something like combobox.

Like this in pic. 
[image]
What I am trying here is

```
<div>
      <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for this i need extra jquery plugins. Is it possible to do this by using SImple html and css with help of Javascript.

Comment: yes. you can do with [`datalist tag`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

Comment: Thanks.. This is working? But will it work for multi select. ANd Can I make it wrapper.. so I can use any where in my project.

Comment: Unfortunately multi select is not  there..For my suggestion => Plugin is Better for requirement

Comment: ok... and then will go for plugging only,

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

**HTML5**

```
<input type="text" name="county" list="countyList" multiple>
<datalist id="countyList">
    <option value="United States">
    <option value="United Kingdom">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. :) +1. Here after selectin, I am getting the same value in list. Second is Multiselect is not possible right.

Comment: @David do you want to put value and text separately? I think multi select is possible. check my edited answer

Comment: Here after selectin, I am getting the same value in list

Comment: Yes, its only support input type="email"